# tail recursion on double factorial equation in C

Tags: c, tail-recursion

I have a difficulty in implementing the tail recursive solution of the following problem:

There is another recursive relation for the double factorial, which also depends on the factorial, which is the above: (for n<20)

[image]

I have to implement a recursive relation of this equation- **which I did as the above code that works**:

```
long long factorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 1)
        return 1;

     return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

long long doublefactorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    return factorial(n) / doublefactorial(n - 1);
}
```

Now I have to implement the same problem using a **tail recursion**. can someone show me how to do this because I cant figure it out. (no need to implement the factorial function also in a tail recursive way)

test cases:

- 5!! = 15
- 10!! = 3840
- 18!! = 185,794,560
- -10!! = 0

Comment: Show us your attempt at tail recursion

Comment: I would recomend you to first try the tail recursive version of the factorial function (which is both easier and findable on the internet)

Comment: @muyustan they asked us to implement only from n=0 to n=20

Comment: @nicomp i dont have an attempt because i dont know how to do this, i know that i need to add more variables to the function but dont know how to turn it into tail recursion.

Comment: n!! = n(n-2)(n-4) ... (1 or 2 depending on whether n is odd or even). So a tail recursive function that computes n!! can look almost identical to that of n!.

Comment: Show us your algorithm.

Comment: @PaulHankin i cant use the equation that you wrote, i can use only the equation that in the picture. and do the tail recursion on that equation.

Comment: @RonenDvorkin I think your recursion is already kinda tail recursion.

Comment: @RonenDvorkin: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tail-recursive version of Factorial function:

```
long factorial(int n, int factor)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return factor;

    return factorial(n-1, factor * n);
}

factorial(5, 1); // 120
```

Here's a tail-recursive double factorial with a simpler logic:

```
long doublefactorial(int n, int factor)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 2)
        return factor;

    return doublefactorial(n-2, factor * n);
}

printf("%d ", doublefactorial(5,1)); // 15
printf("%d ", doublefactorial(10,1)); // 3840
printf("%d ", doublefactorial(18,1)); // 185794560
```

Comment: i know how to do a tail recursion on a regular factorial, i dont know to do a tail recursion on the question that i asked, so if you know it will be helpfull.

Comment: In my opinion, any useful answer to this question is going to explain why the version provided is tail-recursive.

Comment: a tail-recursive function is just a recursive function which returns the recursive call without and other actions (no multiplying/adding/dividing by any value).

Comment: guy, look at the equation that i posted, i also know how to make tail factorial and tail double factorial seperatley, how do i make tail recursion of my equation

Answer (score 1):

If you expand your math a little bit you'll get that the factorial function result is iterating between the numerator and the denominator of the final result.

[image]

so this code will do that in Python

```
def _factorial(n, m):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 1.0 * m
    return _factorial(n - 1, n * m)

def factorial(n):
    return _factorial(n, 1)

def _doublefactorial(n, m, is_even):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n < 2:
        return 1.0 * m

    if is_even:
        m *= factorial(n)
    else:
        m /= factorial(n)

    return _doublefactorial(n - 1, m, (not is_even))

def doublefactorial(n):
    return _doublefactorial(n, 1, True)
```

And in C:

```
unsigned int _factorial(const unsigned int n, const unsigned int m) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return m;
    }
    return _factorial(n - 1, n * m);
}

unsigned int factorial(const unsigned int n) {
    return _factorial(n, 1);
}

double _doublefactorial(const unsigned int n, const double m, const char is_even) {
    double value = m;

    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n < 2) {
        return m;
    }

    if (is_even) {
        value *= factorial(n);
    } else {
        value /= factorial(n);
    }

    return _doublefactorial(n - 1, value, !is_even);
}

double doublefactorial(const unsigned int n) {
    return _doublefactorial(n, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of this [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) function is incomplete: you need an initial value such as **0!! = 1**. From the recurrence definition, it appears that **p!!** is the product of all numbers from 1 to **p** that have the same parity as **p**:

- 5!! = 1 * 3 * 5 = 15
- 6!! = 2 * 4 * 6 = 48
- 10!! = 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 * 10 = 3840

Computing the double factorial by computing the factorial and dividing by the result of the double factorial of the previous number will fail for numbers larger than 19 because of the limited range of integer types and the exponential growth of the factorial function. The double factorial grows quickly too, but its logarithm grows half as fast as that of the factorial function.

Here is an recursive function:

```
unsigned long long doublefactorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    return n * doublefactorial(n - 2);
}
```

Here is a tail recursive implementation with a helper function:

```
unsigned long long doublefactorial_helper(int n, unsigned long long res) {
    if (n < 2)
        return res;
    return doublefactorial(n - 2, res * n);
}

unsigned long long doublefactorial(int n) {
    return doublefactorial_helper(n, n >= 0);
}
```

The trick to convert the first function to a tail recursive one is instead of waiting for the result and multiplying then by `n`, pass an updated intermediary result to the recursive function. The multiplications are performed in the opposite order but will produce the same result (even modulo `ULLONG_MAX+1`).